# In an Android TextView, is it possible to insert paragraphs?

Tags: android, textview

Below is an example of the type of problem that I have. I have data in a pojo that I need to display in a textview... the data has pseudo code that denotes each paragraph with [p]

I would like to somehow parse the [p]'s into paragraphs when they are displayed in the textview. Can this be done? Is there something I can substitute for the [p] that will make a new paragraph in the textview?

```
Question question = new Question();
question.setText("Here is the first paragraph.[p] And this should be the second."); 

TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.qtext);
view.setText(question.getParsedText());
```

Comment: Did you try just using <p>, as it's one of the tags supported by `TextView`: http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html
Having said that, I find Sebi's answer is nicer (and is what I use) as it doesn't needlessly mix HTML markup into your strings.

Comment: YOu know I never even tried that - The answer below seems to do the trick... so which way do you think is better as a practice? /n/n or <p>?

Comment: If you just like to use paragraphs i would use \n\n because then you don't have to do this fromHTML() stuff. On the other hand you have to parse your String. But if you like to color part of the text etc. this html stuff is very nice.

Comment: \n causes problems.  You'll get blank lines occasionally, when Android's line breaking system inserts a break, followed by your hardcoded \n.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hi i would parse the whole String and then replace every [p] with \n or even \n\n as you like.

\n in the String makes a linebreak. For example use it like that:

```
question.setText("Here is the first paragraph.\n\n And this should be the second.");`
```

The method which can do that easily is [String.replace(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char))

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe it was that simple. I had the impression that wouldn't work.

Comment: I tried on android 1.6 emulator and <p> was not working at all. so i had to use \n. it worked like magic.

Comment: This fails often enough to be a bad idea, unfortunately.  You can end up with extra unwanted line breaks.  TextView inserts line breaks itself, and if your \n falls in the same place, you'll see a blank line.

Comment: if you want an indented paragraph, swap \n\n with \n\t

Answer (score 5):

You can also try this

```
String summary = "<html><font color=\"#FFFFFF\"" +
     
             "<p align="+ "\"" +"left" + "\""+ ">" +  "MY data" +"</p>"+
     
                "</font></html>";
mTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(summary));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
TextView tw = findViewById(R.id.t);
tw.setText("first line\nsecond line\nthird line");
```

Comment: Also on this note that \n is new line a paragraph like breakup of text requires 2 lines one blank and then the first line of the second paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

`<br>` and `<p>` work if you need other formatting like bold and are in the middle of an [`Html.fromHtml`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String%29):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("first<br><b>second</b>"));
        setContentView(tv);
    }
}
```

Tested on Android 22.