# Formatting TextView

Tags: android, android-layout

I have bulky-multi paragraph TextView. Contents of the TextView is loaded from Strings.xml.

I would like to show show multiple paragraphs.  When I use `<P></P>` tag in strings.xml it is not reflected, the TextView shows all the script as one single paragraph.

Is there a way to break the text into several paragraphs?

The contents of strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="hello">Hello World, sirukathaikal!</string>
    <string name="app_name">Eelathu Sirukathaikal</string>
    <string name="main_title">®ÆòÐî º¢Ú¸¨¾¸û</string>
    <string name="continue_label">njhlu;f...</string>
    <string name="about_label">nrayp cjtp</string>
    <string name="about_content">,e;j md;nuhapl; nrayp %yk; ,yq;ifiar; Nru;e;j kA+Nurd; vOjpa %d;W rpWfijfis ntspapLfpd;Nwhk;. njhlu;f vd;w nghj;jhidr; nrhLf;fp fijfis thrpf;fTk;. </string>
    <string-array name="story_list">
    <item>Story 1</item>
    <item>Story 2</item>
    <item>Story 3</item>
    </string-array>
    <string name="story_body">
    <p>þ¼õ: ¦¸¡ØõÒ</p>
    <p>§¿Ãõ: ¸¡¨Ä 7.30</p>
    <p>¬ñÎ: 2019</p>

<p>Å¢ó¾¢Â¡ ¾ÉÐ ¨¸Â¢ø þÕìÌõ ¨À¨Â þÚì¸ «¨½ò¾ÀÊ ¿¼óÐ ¦¸¡ñÊÕó¾¡û. Å£¾¢ ¦ÅÈ¢î§º¡Êì ¸¢¼ó¾Ð. ¾ÉÐ ¿¨¼¨Â ¦ÁøÄ ¦ÁøÄ §Å¸ôÀÎò¾¢ì¦¸¡ñ§¼ Å£Î §¿¡ì¸¢ ¿¼ì¸ò ¦¾¡¼í¸¢É¡û.

¨¸Â¢ø þÕìÌõ «ó¾ô ¨ÀÂ¢ý ¦ÀÚÁ¾¢ «ÅÙìÌò¾¡ý ¦¾Ã¢Ôõ. Å£ðÊø «¨ÉÅÕõ þó¾ô ¨ÀÂ¢ø þÕôÀ¨¾ò¾¡ý ±¾¢÷À¡÷òÐ ¸¡ò¾¢Õì¸¢ýÈ¡÷¸û. Â¡÷ ¸ñ½¢Öõ ÀðÎÅ¢¼Á¡ø ¦ºýÚÅ¢¼§ÅñÎõ ±ýÀ¾¢ø ÌÈ¢Â¡¸ þÕó¾¡û. ÀòÐ ¬ñÎ¸ÙìÌ Ó¾ø þó¾ þ¼ò¾¢ø þó§¿Ãò¾¢ø ºÉõ ÍõÁ¡ §ƒ.. §ƒ… ±ýÚ ¿¼Á¡Îõ. þô§À¡ ±øÄ¡õ ¾¨Ä¸£ú.

º¢ó¾¨É¸Ç¢ø ÍÆýÈÅ¡Ú ¿¼óÐ¦¸¡ñÊÕó¾¡û Å¢ó¾¢Â¡. «ó¾ ºó¾¢¨Âì ¸¼óÐÅ¢ð¼¡ø ¾ý Å£ð¨¼ «Îò¾ 5 ¿¢Á¢¼ò¾¢ø «¨¼óÐÅ¢¼Ä¡õ ±ýÈ ¿õÀ¢ì¨¸Â¢ø ¿¨¼Â¢ý Å¢¨Ã¨Åì ÜðÊÂÅ¡Ú ºó¾¢¨Â §¿ì¸¢ ¿¼ì¸ò ¦¾¡¼í¸¢É¡û.

¾¢Ë÷ ±ýÚ ±í¸¢Õó§¾¡ ´Õ «ÊÀðÎ ¦¿Ç¢ó¾ ¼¡¼¡ þýÊ¸¡ ¸¡Ã¢ø ¿¡ý¨¸óÐ þ¨Ç»÷¸û. ¸¡÷ ºò¨¾ò¨¾ Å¢¼ «Å÷¸û §À¡ð¼ ºò¾§Á «¾¢¸Á¡¸ þÕó¾Ð. ´Õò¾ý ¸¡Ð Ìò¾¢Â¢Õó¾¡ý ÁüÈÅý ¸ñþ¨ÁÂ¢ø ²§¾¡ Ìò¾¢Â¢Õó¾¡ý.

“§¼ö «í¸ À¡Õ¼¡! ²ö……….. ±ýÉ ¨¸Â¢Ä?” ¸¡Ã¢ø þÕó¾ ´Õò¾ý °¨ÇÂ¢ð¼¡ý.</p>


<p>ÌÉ¢ó¾ ¾¨Ä ¿¢Á¢Ã¡Áø Å¢ó¾¢Â¡ «ó¾ þ¼ò¾¢ø þÕóÐ ¦ÁøÄ ¿¸Ãò ¦¾¡¼í¸¢É¡ø. «Å¨Ç º¢È¢Ð ¸¼óÐ ¿¢ýÚ þÕó¾ ¸¡÷ þô§À¡Ð, ¸¢Ã£î ±ýÈ ºò¾§¾¡Î «Åû ÓýÉ¡ø ÅóÐ ¿¢ýÈÐ. ¸¡Ã¢ø þÕóÐ ¿¡ýÚ þ¨Ç»÷¸Ùõ ¾¼ ¾¼¦ÅÉ þÈí¸¢É÷. ´ù¦Å¡Õò¾ý ¸ñ½¢Öõ ¦ÅÈ¢ ¾¡ñ¼ÅÁ¡ÊÂÐ.

´Õ «Ê ÓýÛìÌ ±ÎòÐ ¨Åò¾ ´Õò¾ý Å¢ó¾¢Â¡ ¨¸Â¢ø þÕó¾ ¨À¨Â ÀÈ¢ò¾¡ý. ¨À¨Â ¾¢ÈóÐ ¯û§Ç À¡÷ò¾Åý, ÁüÈÅ÷¸¨Çô À¡÷òÐ ÒýÉ¨¸Ô¼ý ¾¨ÄÂ¡ðÊÉ¡ý.

“§¼ö… ¾¡¼¡!!!” Å¢ó¾¢Â¡ ÀÈ¢ò¾Åý ¸ýÉò¾¢ø º¼¡÷ ±ýÚ ´Õ «¨È Å¢ð¼¡û. «¨Èó¾ ºò¾õ µöÅ¾üÌû ´Õ ºò¾õ ‘ÎÁ£ø’. Å¢ó¾¢Â¡Å¢ý ¯¼ø ¸£§Æ ºÃ¢Â «Åû ¯¼Ä¢ø þÕóÐ þÃò¾ý ÌÒ ÌÒ ±É ¦ÅÇ¢§ÂÈò ¦¾¡¼í¸¢ÂÐ.

Å¢ó¾¢Â¡Å¢üÌ ÍÂ ¿¢¨É× ¦ÁøÄ ¦ÁøÄ «¸Äò ¦¾¡¼í¸¢ÂÐ. ¸ñ¸û þÕð¼ò ¦¾¡¼í¸¢ÂÐ. ¸¨¼º¢Â¡¸ ¸ñ ã¼ ÓýÉ÷, ¾ý ¨ÀÂ¢ø þÕó¾ À¡ñ Ðñ¨¼ «ó¾ì ¸ÂÅ÷¸û Å¢ÄíÌ¸¨Çô §À¡Ä À¢öòÐ ¯ñÀ¨¾ì ¸ñ¼¡û. ¦ÁøÄ ¦ÁøÄ «Åû ¯Ä¸õ þÕÇò ¦¾¡¼í¸¢ÂÐ.

À¢.Ì: Ôò¾õ Å¢¨ÃÅ¢ø µÂ¡Å¢ð¼¡ø ´Õ¿¡û ŠÃ£ Äí¸¡Å¢ø þÐ ¿¼ì¸ô §À¡ÅÐ ¿¢îºÂÁ</p>

    </string>

    </resources>
```

BodyStory1.java:

```
package com.mayuonline.com.esiru;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class BodyStory1 extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.story_body);


        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/kaviri.TTF");  
        TextView tvBody = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.story_body);
        tvBody.setTypeface(tf);
    }
}
```

storyBody1.java after adding setText():
    package com.mayuonline.com.esiru;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class BodyStory1 extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.story_body);
        setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.story_body)));

        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/kaviri.TTF");  
        TextView tvBody = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.story_body);
        tvBody.setTypeface(tf);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post a sample entry out of `strings.xml` that exhibits the behavior you describe? `<p>` elements should be honored, though possibly only in lowercase.

Comment: please find the file content also. dont worry about the jumbled letters as it is TSCII type of encording for Tamil. I'm embedding a Tamil TSCII font for the app too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When setting the text of the `TextView`, try using
`Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/kaviri.TTF");

TextView tvBody = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.story_body);
tvBody.setTypeface(tf);
tvBody.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.story_body))));`

Comment: it gives a compliation error "The method setText(Spanned) is undefined for the type BodyStory1" :((

Comment: What is `BodyStory1`? Have you tried using a simple string first? Maybe you would be better off using a `WebView` for this, what do you think?

Comment: please find the BodyStory1 code above. Yep, if nothing works for this method then I'll b stucked with WebView and can load the content from an offline HTML page.. That also sounds better. But again I have this embedding font problem.. dont knw whether it'll work on WebView.

Comment: I tried for <string name="story_body">
    <p>This is a simple test.</p>
    <p>This is another simple test</p>
    </string> but still no luck. Both sentences comes in one line.

Comment: You can use a custom font for a `WebView` by setting it in a CSS file, but there is a known bug for it for Android 2.0 and 2.1. Can you include in the code how you set the text for `tvBody`?

Comment: ok, CSS and all then I have start from the scracth.. I can give it a try to. please find the code above with setText. But that didn't work.

Comment: Oh, you should move the setText bit to after the findViewById. `TextView tvBody = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.story_body);
        tvBody.setTypeface(tf);
        tvBody.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.story_body)));`

Comment: Edited my answer to illustrate my last comment.

Comment: Thanks. I did that now. Now no compilation error but the result is same. Emulator prints both sentences in one line :((

Comment: here is the solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979433/in-an-android-textview-is-it-possible-to-insert-paragraphs

Comment: Hi Mayu, I have also been using <br /> and it works as well. :)