# Write a paragraph using textview on Android

Tags: android, textview

I want to write a paragraph as part of my mobile application. How do I go about it?

Comment: What do you mean by a paragraph? What special features do you want that can't be meet by a regular TextView? maybe you are thinking of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979433/in-an-android-textview-is-it-possible-to-insert-paragraphs ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use \n to break line.

Example:

```
TextView t = findViewById(R.id.text);
t.setText("This is the first line\nThis is the second line\nThird line...");
```

Answer (score 10):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="text_with_paragraphs">
        Can this contain a lot of text? Can it contain \n a newline? Yes, it can.
        Adding a 2nd line like this should work.
        It should not cause parsing errors.
    </string>
<resources>
```

So you can make a reference to it like:

```
android:text="@string/text_with_paragraphs"
```

Reference: http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Smartphones/Android/Q_27925834.html