# How to format text in string displayed in TextView

Tags: android, string, formatting, textview

I'm trying to format text in string, which is displyed in `TextView`.

```
<string name="register"> <p align="center"><u><b><i>Something</i></b></u></p> 
                         <p align="right">Blablabla</p>
```

Underline, bolt and italics are working, but new paragraph and align isn't. Am I doing something wrong? Is there some other tag for end of a paragraph/new line?

Comment: not all the html tags are supported by the method Html.fromHtml

Comment: Possible duplicate of [write a paragraph using textview in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5040574/write-a-paragraph-using-textview-in-android) + http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9754076/which-html-tags-are-supported-by-android-textview + http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529068/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-styles-inside-a-textview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refer here http://bigknol.com/android-supported-html-tags-textview-string/

Not all html tags are supported in android. As per the link only the following tags are supported:

```
<big></big>
<small></small>
<bold></bold>
<strike></strike>
<a href=””></a>
<sup></sup>
<sub></sub>
<u></u>
<i></i>
<tt></tt>
```

Also refer here [Which HTML tags are supported by Android TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9754076/3492139)
Another reference is here http://javatechig.com/android/display-html-in-android-textview

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h2>Heading</h2><br><p>data about something</p>"));
```

Comment: some tags are unavailable in android