# New Paragraph from Strings android studio

Tags: android, xml, textview

So, I have a long string, the problem is that I made somehow in the xml file to appear paragraphs , but when I run the app on my phone, it doesn't.
The code looks like this

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="-126dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cap1anxietate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:text="@string/Aspecte_generale"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp" />


</ScrollView>
```

In the xml, it looks like this :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvkYK.png)

and in the phone like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3h69.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In an Android TextView, is it possible to insert paragraphs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979433/in-an-android-textview-is-it-possible-to-insert-paragraphs). You can add line breaks easily by adding line break characters (`\n`) in the XML, but indenting the text at the start of the paragraph may require some of the HTML tricks, or adding non-breaking space characters (`\u00A0`) at the start of each paragraph.